# Why connecting two secondary windings together in an aiding dot-orientation parallel configuration will result in no output?

Tags: voltage, transformer, ground, parallel, secondary-winding

I need clarification on what would happen if the transformer is in aiding dot-orientation parallel configuration as shown below.

Would that be the same as connecting two batteries, in parallel, as shown below?

Would the high current flowing in the loop cause the transformer to blow up?

[image: Aiding-dot orientation Parallel]

[image: DC batteries connected in reverse parallel configuration]

Comment: Yes, assuming the primary windings are being driven overall in-phase (please do not try this in real life).

Comment: Not the same because batteries are DC and naturally contain energy that can readily flow with no chance of deactivating them.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*Figure 1. Here are two series-connected transformers with the outputs short-circuited.*

- If you measure the output on the two wires on the right you will get 0 V as there is a wire link between them.
- If you remove the short-circuit you will get an AC voltage of twice that of one transformer on its own.

[image]

*Figure 2. Series-connected batteries with a short-circuit.*

To understand this better let's redraw it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKQi6Y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 3. (Figure 2 redrawn.)*

- The centre schematic is electrically equivelant to the left one but it makes it more obvious that the battery stack is short circuited. If these batteries have a low internal resistance then a very high current will flow.
- The right image makes it a bit clearer that if there is internal resistance in the batteries that R1 and R2 will form a potential divider with [1] being half-way between V+ and V- and therefore 0 V with respect to [2].

Both the AC and DC circuits are short-circuits. Don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same if you consider the leads coming out on the right as the output.

the first image would be more like this with batteries:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsdjj1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

While the second would be like this with a transformer:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffS6cT.png)</sup>

In both cases the current would be short circuited.

Answer (score 0):

> Why connecting two secondary windings together in an aiding dot-orientation parallel configuration will result in no output?

Your first sketch does not show the transformer secondaries in parallel. Rather, it shows them in series short-circuit that would undoubtedly damage the transformers.

Likewise, your second sketch shows the batteries in series short-circuit that could cause severe damage.

Trying either is to risk serious injury.

The following schematics show the right way to parallel-connect / series-connect batteries as well as transformers.

[image]

[image]